# Could not find or load main class SerialTestGET

Tags: java, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to execute the program on Linux , raspberry pi and getting error

> Could not find or load main class SerialTestGET.

the program:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class SerialTestGET implements SerialPortEventListener {
    SerialPort serialPort;
    static int sensorValue = 0;
    /** The port we're normally going to use. */
    private static final String PORT_NAMES[] = {
        "/dev/tty.usbserial-A9007UX1",
        // Mac OS X
        "/dev/ttyACM0",
        // Raspberry Pi
        "/dev/ttyUSB0",
        // Linux
        "COM3",
        // Windows
    };
    /**
* A BufferedReader which will be fed by a InputStreamReader
* converting the bytes into characters
* making the displayed results codepage independent
*/
    private BufferedReader input;
    /** The output stream to the port */
    private OutputStream output;
    /** Milliseconds to block while waiting for port open */
    private static final int TIME_OUT = 2000;
    /** Default bits per second for COM port. */
    private static final int DATA_RATE = 9600;

    public void initialize() {
        // the next line is for Raspberry Pi and
        // gets us into the while loop and was suggested here was suggested 
        //http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=81&amp;t=32186
        System.setProperty("gnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts", "/dev/ttyACM0");

        CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
        Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

        //First, Find an instance of serial port as set in PORT_NAMES.
        while (portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
            CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
            for (String portName: PORT_NAMES) {
                if (currPortId.getName().equals(portName)) {
                    portId = currPortId;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (portId == null) {
            System.out.println("Could not find COM port.");
            return;
        }

        try {
            // open serial port, and use class name for the appName.
            serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(this.getClass().getName(), TIME_OUT);

            // set port parameters
            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(DATA_RATE, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

            // open the streams
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream()));
            output = serialPort.getOutputStream();

            // add event listeners
            serialPort.addEventListener(this);
            serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }

    /**
* This should be called when you stop using the port.
* This will prevent port locking on platforms like Linux.
*/
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (serialPort != null) {
            serialPort.removeEventListener();
            serialPort.close();
        }
    }

    /**
* Handle an event on the serial port. Read the data and print it.
*/
    public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
        if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
            try {
                String inputLine = input.readLine();
                //System.out.println(inputLine);
                sendGet(inputLine);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.toString());
                serialPort.removeEventListener();
                serialPort.close();
            }
        }
        // Ignore all the other eventTypes, but you should consider the other ones.
    }

    // HTTP GET request
    public void sendGet(String inputLine) throws Exception {

        try {
            //if difference is more than 3 then send data to SAP HANA
            if (inputLine != null && inputLine.length() > 0 && Math.abs(sensorValue - Integer.parseInt(inputLine)) > 3) {

                sensorValue = Integer.parseInt(inputLine);
                //Considering that A001 sensor is connection with this raspberry pie for now
                //we can even pass this with command line but for simplicityhardcoding it
                //Replace with your HANA server URL and port number
                String url = " ";

                url = url + inputLine;

                URL obj = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

                // optional default is GET
                con.setRequestMethod("GET");

                //add request header
                //con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
                int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
                if (responseCode == 200) {
                    System.out.println("OK value:" + inputLine);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Error: Response code " + responseCode);
                }

            }
            System.out.println("OK value: Less than 3");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
            serialPort.removeEventListener();
            serialPort.close();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    throws Exception {
        SerialTestGET main = new SerialTestGET();
        main.initialize();

        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                //the following line will keep this app alive for 1000 seconds,
                //waiting for events to occur and responding to them (printing incoming messages to console).
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000000);
                } catch(InterruptedException ie) {}
            }
        };
        t.start();
        System.out.println("Started");
    }
}
```

all files are placed in the required folder

I am running the file from the path java file is located.

[image]
[image]

Comment: oh my... you need to start indenting your code

Comment: Make sure you don't have envvar CLASSPATH set to a value that omits the directory you are using (usually as 'dot' `.`)